# Using the cardboard to see the real world

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

There are two normal cameras and one Cardboard([VR Box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QezB4sjvJ7s)). The two cameras are placed on the front of the Cardboard. The two cameras can be connected to a computer via USB port.

I need to develop a VR application for the android phone to see the real world like [this](http://www.cuddleburrito.com/flrnmrr/2016/10/16/depth-perception-with-two-usb-cameras-mounted-to-headset)

My question is how can I connect the two cameras to the phone so that the phone can view the real world inside the cardboard?

Comment: Your question is either unclear, too broad, or opinion based. "Can Unity do that?" Dunno, probably.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the question. My major problem is how the phone can connect to the cameras?